# batch file not copying files even though it says it did.. error: "UNC paths are not Supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory"

Tags: batch-file

Here is my code. All the files are exactly where im pointing to, except in the end after running the .bat file, it says that SPSupport.BHF is not found and when I go into the directory, SPSupport.BHF is not there. any ideas on what's wrong? Basically, if it's windows 7, it downloads the windows 7 file in a certain location, other wise it downloads the windows xp file. I'm using a windows xp computer and when I run the .bat file, in the cmd it prints out all of these commands correctly except on the last step when I try to run it, it says internal or external command not found and when I go into the directory, the files aren't even copied successfully.

Note: It also says "UNC paths are not Supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory" at the begging. could that be why? What does that mean?

```
@echo off


mkdir C:\Windows\Temp

if exist "C:\Users\" goto win7

if exist "C:\Documents and Settings\" goto winxp

:win7
xcopy /s /Y \\torwan\Shared\SPSupport.BHF C:\Windows\Temp
xcopy /s /Y \\torwan\Shared\PCA.megamation.CIF C:\Windows\Temp
START C:\Windows\Temp\SPSupport.BHF
goto exit

:winxp
mkdir "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\pcAnywhere"
echo d xcopy /s /Y \\torwan\Shared\xp\SPSupport.BHF "C:\Documents and Settings\All   Users

\Application Data\Symantec\pcAnywhere"
echo d xcopy /s /Y \\torwan\Shared\xp\PCA.megamation.CIF "C:\Documents and Settings\All     Users

\Application Data\Symantec\pcAnywhere"
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application  Data\Symantec\pcAnywhere\SPSupport.BHF"
PAUSE
goto exit

:exit
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems here. You have two extra spaces between `All` and `Users` in the first `xcopy` for XP. Also, you're not actually running `xcopy` because of the `echo` at the beginning of those lines; you're just echoing `d xcopy /s /Y....`. You also have an extra space between `Application` and `Data` in the line just before `PAUSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the bat file from the local machine instead of running it from a network drive?  You have an extra space between Application and Data in "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application  Data\

Comment: I have to run from a network drive. What I tried was create another file which copies SPSupport.bat (the file who's code is posted above) into C:\ and then runs SPSupport.bat from C:\. When I do this, the UNC error doesn't show up except it still doesn't copy the files successfully :/ Should I try copying all the files into C:\ instead of just the .bat file?

Comment: Executing from a network drive becomes more difficult as you migrate to Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: Okay perfect, thanks, I basically created a .bat file which moves all of the files into a local folder.

Comment: That would be best.  So you are all set then?